# Jquery Validate mostrar gif al hacer submit

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Estoy realizando una validacion de formularios y utilizo `Jquery Validate()` pero tengo un problema. Os indico el código

```
$("#formBloqueo1").validate({
    success: function() {
         $("body").css({"overflow-y":"hidden"});
         var alto = $(window).height();
         $("body").append("<div id='pre-load-web'><div id='imagen-load'><img src='/img/loading.gif' alt=''/><h1>Realizando Validación</h1></div></div>"); 
         $("#pre-load-web").css({"height":alto+"px"}); 
         $("#imagen-load").css({"margin-top":(alto/2)-30+"px"});
         //Aqui realizo mis comprobaciones

        $("#formBloqueo1").attr('action', nuevaUrl);
        $("#formBloqueo1").attr('method', 'POST');

        $("#formBloqueo1").submit();//Hago submit
```

El problema es que con el código de arriba, el html  de pre-load-web aparece duplicado y el gif no aparece,
pero si esta linea:

```
$("#formBloqueo1").submit();//Hago submit
```

La comento para que no se haga submit, el div aparece perfecto y el gif también, alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema??

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente estés inadvertidamente reinvocando la validación al hacer el `.submit()` dentro del `success:` handler

En lugar de resolver el selector del form con jquery, es decir `$("#formBloqueo1")`, prueba a utilizar el selector ya resuelto por `validate()`, y en lugar de hacerlo en el `success:` hazlo en el `submitHandler:` algo así como

```
 $("#formBloqueo1").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       ...
       form.submit();
```

Comment: Ese era el problema, muchas gracias, ya esta solucionado